# How can I get Folder detail from document Id in Alfresco using cmis api

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis

I have one question. How can I get Folder Name,Id etc...(Folder details) from document Id in alfresco using cmis api?
Is there any way???
Thanks

Comment: Those should all be available as the properties on the folder object. What did you try? How far did you get? Where did you get stuck? etc

Comment: I used those...but didn't get succeed .. For ex: My docId is "workspace://SpacesStore/XXXXXXXX" then how can I get Folder name from this particular id?? This document is belongs to which folder??? I didn't get those api..please let me know if any..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer..use following line..

```
 ObjectData bindingParent=cmisSession.getBinding().getNavigationService().getFolderParent(cmisSession.getRepositoryInfo().getId(), doc.getId(), null, null);
System.out.println("\n --> id "+ bindingParent.getId());
```

Answer (score 2):

This one is shorter:

```
// get the first parent of the document 
Folder parent = doc.getParents().get(0);

System.out.println("ID: "+ parent.getId());
System.out.println("Name: "+ parent.getName());
```